# Moving bootstrap horizontal step chain vertically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 form process steps chain that show the steps horizontally . on mobile devices the horizontal step chain become so small and don't look good . i want to make that chain vertically on smaller devices how can i do this @ media (786px)

i am using this snippet ... http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/form-process-steps
here is HTML

```
 <div class="row bs-wizard" style="border-bottom:0;">

            <div class="col-xs-3 bs-wizard-step complete">
              <div class="text-center bs-wizard-stepnum">Step 1</div>
              <div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar"></div></div>
              <a href="#" class="bs-wizard-dot"></a>
              <div class="bs-wizard-info text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-3 bs-wizard-step complete"><!-- complete -->
              <div class="text-center bs-wizard-stepnum">Step 2</div>
              <div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar"></div></div>
              <a href="#" class="bs-wizard-dot"></a>
              <div class="bs-wizard-info text-center">Nam mollis tristique. Aliquam erat voat</div>
            </div>

             <div class="col-xs-3 bs-wizard-step active"><!-- complete -->
              <div class="text-center bs-wizard-stepnum">Step 3</div>
              <div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar"></div></div>
              <a href="#" class="bs-wizard-dot"></a>
              <div class="bs-wizard-info text-center">Integer semper dolor ac auctor rutrum. Duisendum bibendum</div>
            </div>
  </div>
```

thanx

Comment: how did you make the bs-wizard-stepnum to work, if i might ask?

Answer (score 1):

I had tried using following CSS for 1000px media screen.

```
@media (max-width:1000px){
.bs-wizard {min-width:325px !important;overflow:auto}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step {transform: rotate(+90deg);display:block;margin:0 auto 0 auto;height:160px;width:160px !important}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step .bs-wizard-stepnum, .bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step .bs-wizard-info {transform: rotate(-90deg);position:relative}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step .bs-wizard-stepnum {top:144px}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step .bs-wizard-info {bottom:130px}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step > .bs-wizard-dot {top:46.5%}
```

}

and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I am using a simplistic Bootsrap4/fontawesome stepper like below, it can be converted to angular component, No fancy and proprietary dependencies

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Stepper</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="panel">
  <h1>Stepper</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-auto ml-1 text-secondary"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Fill out your contact </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 m-0" ><hr/></div>
    <div class="col-md-auto" ><i class="fa fa-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Fill out your car information</div> 
    <div class="col-md-1" ><hr/></div>
    <div class="col-md-auto text-secondary" ><i class="fa fa-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Done</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```